# Clickable box malformed in TOC when using math in heading and the Latin Modern Math font

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, hyperref, unicode-math, latin-modern

The clickable box (the actual hyperlink) in the TOC is too heigh when using the Latin Modern Math font.

[image: clickable box too large]

Using Cambria Math everything looks normal. Using the `\texorpdfstring{}{}` command does not help.

Minimal example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage[psdextra]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{My first chapter}
\section{My second chapter which includes $\pi$ and $\gamma$}
\section{My third chapter}
\end{document}
```

### Update

It looks like it is a problem with the internal height of the glyphs in the font which hyperref does not use correctly. When viewing the font using using quick view on Mac a similar problem appear with huge space between lines.

[image: Latin Modern Math]
[image: Latin Modern Regular]

Comment: I don't have Latin Modern Math, but with other fonts this fixes the problem: `\section{My second chapter which includes \texorpdfstring{pi}{$\pi$} and \texorpdfstring{gamma}{$\gamma$}}`

Comment: LuaLaTeX runs fine. `hyperref` only inserts the link annotation specials, it does not measure the link box in case of XeTeX. Thus it done in XeTeX/xdvipdfmx.

Comment: @Heiko Is there any news you are aware of concerning the links? It would be nice if this question finally gets an answer :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I do not have any news that I am aware of.

Comment: test with tex live 2016 shows that this is now working properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem no longer exists with tex live 2016.